# Rspec how to check whether table hasn't beed modified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, hash, rspec

i'm writing tests(rspec-rails) for my application. I would like to check whether running script hasn't changed any object in table. 
I tried using Table.hash or just adding each object hash, but those values seams to not change, when i make some changes in objects. So after executing this code(Someobject is just an example - normal table):

```
hash1a = Someobject.hash
o = Someobject.first 
hash2a = o.hash
o.field = o.field + 1
o.save!
hash1b = Someobject.hash
hash2b = o.hash
```

`hash1a == hash1b` and `hash2a == hash2b`. So obviously i can't use any of these methods to check whether any object has changed.

Currently i'm using this code:

```
def run_script #run script and btw check whether it throws exception
    lambda { eval File.read(File.join(Rails.root, 'lib', 'tasks', 'some_script.rb')) }.should_not raise_error()
  end

  def objects_hash #calculates hash of each order json version and than concatenates all strings and return it
    hash = ''
    Someobject.each do |object|
      hash+= Digest::SHA1.base64digest object.as_json.to_s
    end
    hash
  end


  ....

expect {run_script}.to_not change{objects_hash} #expect run_script to not change any object
```

Basically it converts each object to json, then to string and then calculates hash of this string. All strings(hashes) are concatenated
and this value is returned. So this line `expect {run_script}.to_not change{objects_hash} #expect run_script to not change any object` 
calculate hash of all objects, run script, calculate new hash and compare new hash with old one.

It is working fine, but i think that there is a better way to achieve this. The question is - how? I'm using rails 3.2.13 and mongoid.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable solution to see if any document has changed in a collection, unless you want to check the log files, etc.

Comment: I don't need to check log files etc(just all objects of one table), but i'm just searching for better solution in described situation.

Comment: I'm saying you might be able to use log files to look for modifications. But, as I said, I don't see any reason to not do what you propose. It's not going to be super fast, but for the use case you have, that doesn't seem like it should be an issue.

Comment: use this command:  db.runCommand({dbhash:1})

Comment: @AsyaKamsky - your solution(a bit modified) is working, thank you very much! At the end i've used this code `expect {run_script}.to_not change{Mongoid::Sessions.default.command(dbHash:1)['collections']['tablename']}` and it's working fine. Please post your comment as an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB has a database command `dbhash` - it's used internally by sharding to check if config database collections have changed or not.

Example of usage and output:

```
> db.runCommand({dbhash:1})
{
    "numCollections" : 3,
    "host" : "asyasmacbook.local",
    "collections" : {
        "usertable" : "57fd76283e32631be17d03cd684ab7db"
    },
    "md5" : "b5cfcfca8dd0e4731676139aff4cf4e7",
    "timeMillis" : 274,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comparing collection's hash to its previous value lets you determine if there have been any changes in it.

Comment: More precisely - i've used this code: `expect {run_script}.to_not change{Mongoid::Sessions.default.command(dbHash:1)['collections']['tablename']}`. Of course this solution works only with Mongoid, but for me looks better than solution which i presented in question.